# Is it possible to use testthat::expect_output to expect a carriage return?

Tags: r, testthat

I'm trying to test my package to ensure that a message printed to the screen ends in a carriage return.  When I try to match the carriage return at the end, it never succeeds.  is there a way to match the carriage return?

```
library(testthat)
foo <- function() cat("Hello\n")
expect_output(foo(), "Hello\n")
#> Error: `foo\(\)` does not match "Hello\n".
#> Actual value: "Hello"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works, looks like the it is the cat behaviour

Take a look at the help for the fill parameter (defaults to FALSE)

```
foo <- function() {cat ("Hello\n",fill=TRUE)}
expect_output(foo(), "Hello\n")
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!  The help to the `fill` argument doesn't read that it would fix the issue to me since I'm adding an explicit "\n", but it does!  Sometimes R has black magic. :)

Comment: FYI, I created a bug report to hopefully improve the documentation: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17492